# Elasticsearch /_cluster/health nodes reports higher number than /_nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a small cluster of three machines. When we initially deployed the solution, we realized we did not have enough storage available for our anticipated need. So we brought down the ES service on the first node, attached and configured an EBS volume for the machine, moved the data to the new volume, updated the configuration file to point to the new data dir and brought the service back up. All was well. The cluster went green pretty quickly. Same for the next two machines. Then we realized that we had not updated the configuration file on the second node. So we stopped the service, updated the configuration file and started the service. Our cluster health has remained yellow since then. Interestingly, I'm seeing a discrepancy between the number of nodes reported in the /_cluster/health endpoint and the /_nodes endpoint. Also of interest is the fact that since we are in AWS, we are using unicast discovery and are explicitly pointing to the other nodes. I see that it's trying to initialize shards, but do not know where/how/why it's trying to do that. Any thoughts?

`/_cluster/health`

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "the_name_of_my_cluster",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 5,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 5,
  "active_primary_shards" : 20,
  "active_shards" : 33,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 4,
  "unassigned_shards" : 3
}
```

`/_nodes`

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "cluster_name" : "abc_cluster",
  "nodes" : {
    "identifier" : {
      "name" : "node3",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/ip3:9300]",
      "version" : "0.90.5",
      "http_address" : "inet[/ip3:9200]"
    },
    "identifier" : {
      "name" : "node2",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/ip2:9300]",
      "version" : "0.90.5",
      "http_address" : "inet[/ip2:9200]"
    },
    "identifier" : {
      "name" : "node1",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/ip1:9300]",
      "version" : "0.90.5",
      "http_address" : "inet[/ip1:9200]"
    }
  }
}
```

## Edit

I started tailing the ES logs on the second node. It turns out it was trying to reach our third node on 9301 and 9302

```
[2014-04-24 20:08:37,005][WARN ][cluster.service          ] [node2] failed to reconnect to node [node3][identifying_info][inet[/ip3:9302]]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [node3][inet[/ip3:9302]] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:675)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:608)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:576)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:129)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$ReconnectToNodes.run(InternalClusterService.java:475)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /ip3:9302
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientBoss.java:137)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    ... 3 more
[2014-04-24 20:09:17,042][WARN ][cluster.service          ] [node2] failed to reconnect to node [node3][identifying_info][inet[/ip3:9301]]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [node3][inet[/ip3:9301]] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:675)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:608)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:576)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:129)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$ReconnectToNodes.run(InternalClusterService.java:475)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /ip3:9301
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientBoss.java:137)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    ... 3 more
```

So we opened a range from 9300-9303 for the ES security group.

Voila. We have a green cluster.

`/_cluster/health`

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "the_name_of_my_cluster",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 6,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 6,
  "active_primary_shards" : 20,
  "active_shards" : 40,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

HOWEVER - we are showing 6 nodes now instead of the 3 that I expect. What gives?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but can you check if you have multiple elasticsearch instances running on the same nodes?

Comment: You must be clairvoyant. node has 1 process. node 2 has 2 processes and node3 has three processes. We had some trouble getting the service to start initially, but got it running. Question is - what to do now? On node3, we have /esdata/elasticsearch/clustername/nodes/{0,1,2} each with a shard data file in it. How can we get back to normal state?

Comment: OK - The nodes endpoint is now reporting 6 nodes. Which is good in that we don't have different numbers between cluster/health and nodes. I believe I can use the /nodes/nodeId/_shutdown endpoint to shutdown the errant nodes (those running on ports other than 9300). I will try that and report results. It will have to be EOD.